# How do I know how much each address own in a wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

My wallet has 3 address. One main address is shared with my other computer. The other addresses are not.

Does money belong to a specific address or to a whole wallet? What happen if I send money to one of my own addresses?

What happen if I delete some of the addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, bitcoins aren't sent to a wallet.

The Bitcoin blockchain works as a ledger.  A "wallet" simply holds the keys that allow you to spend funds.

If you are simply asking how to monitor balances for certain addresses, there are third party services such as [BTCBalance.net](http://BTCBalance.net) which make this possible.

Comment: My wallet has 3 addresses. How do I store all funds on just one?